# Can't get logging to file to work in Gunicorn 19.x (works in version 18)

Tags: django, logging, gunicorn

I recently updated from Gunicorn 18 to Gunicorn 19.3, and suddenly, I couldn't find any messages in the log files anymore.

I'm running with Nginx + Gunicorn and have set it up like this, which outputs to error.log when using version 18, but not 19.x:

**upstart script**

```
exec ../../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn
     --bind unix:/tmp/app.sock
     --access-logfile ../../access.log
     --error-logfile ../../error.log
     app.wsgi:application
```

**settings.py**

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

**Example of logging try:**

```
import logging

class SomeView(TemplateView):
    logging.warning('Print warning')
```

How can I get it to work as expected, using Gunicorn 19.x?

Comment: Same problem here. No way to make it work (even the normal access log).

Comment: This was an undocumented behavior that was removed in Gunicorn 19. Due to community feedback it has been added again with an explicit option in version 19.6. See my answer, below, and don't hesitate to engage directly with the project on GitHub if you experience regressions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Versions of Gunicorn prior to 19 would redirect stdout and stderr to the gunicorn log file. That behavior enabled logging configurations like yours to specify a console handler and thereby write to the gunicorn error log file.

In 19, Gunicorn stopped providing this redirection.

Due to feedback from the community, the feature was re-added as [an option](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#capture-output) in Gunicorn 19.6.

Comment: Thanks. After enabling --capture-output lgging works again.